# Using windows azure connect

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-connect

Is it possible for an asp.net mvc web api deployed on azure to connect to on premise db using windows authentication?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far...

Comment: i need to know how to domain join webRole if i don't have admin access

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you have to:

1. [Domain Join your WebRole](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2010/12/10/domain-joining-windows-azure-roles.aspx)
2. [Programmatically set AppPool credentials to a user who has access to the local DB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2011/03/16/windows-azure-connect-use-case-enable-windows-authentication-to-sql-server-using-application-pool-credentials.aspx).